# How to get data without duplicates for two columns from the same table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, sql-function

select DISTINCT column1,  (select DISTINCT column2 from table1 ) from table1

I want both column1 and column2 value without duplicate

Comment: Can you please add some info clearly with result output.                    
   select distinct column1,column2 from table      would do

Comment: Can you present example data you have and expected result?

Comment: .i was working in month selection table with column1 contain n number of month name in english and column2 contain n number of month name in local language. i want month in english & local language in 12 rows with two column without duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT value 
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
     ('COLUMN1', Column1),
     ('COLUMN2', Column2)
) c(col, value)
WHERE value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Its working can u pls help as how to order it by month wise

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly what you want. Please be more specific, maybe post a new questions explaining exactly what you want to do and what you tried until now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct column1
               ,column2
from table1
```

Comment: i don't know if he is asking for that ,for example [a,b][a,c] ar not duplicate in row but in column according with what he is asking .

Comment: i tried it but not Working...i was working in month selection table with column1 contain n number of month name in english and column2 contain n number of  month name in local language. i want month in english & local language in 12 rows with two column without duplication

Answer (score 0):

If you have only few duplicates, then

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2 from table1
```

If you have many duplicates, then

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 from table1 GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between these two statements?  They are syntactically identical and doing the same thing inside the SQL Engine

Answer (score 0):

select distinct column1,column2 from table1;